# Sum of two discrete stable random variables

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, random

It is known that if $X$, $X_1$ and $X_2$ are iid random draw from a continuous stable distribution, then $X_1 + X_2$  has the same distribution as $a + b X$. Parameters $a$ and $b$ are determined by
$$E[X_1 + X_2] = E[a + b X],$$
$$V [X_1 + X_2] = V[a + b X],$$
where $V$ represents variance.

Is there a similar way of determining the distribution of $X_1+X_2$ in terms of $X$ (say, $a + b X$ if that is possible) if our three random variables are iid draws from a discrete stable distribution?

Comment: @coudy Uniform distribution is not stable

Comment: It depends on how you define "stable".  If it is that the sum of any two independent random variables from the family (not necessarily identically distributed) is a member of the family, then no: the sum of two iid Poisson random variable is a Poisson random variable (so discrete stable) but cannot be expressed as $a+bX$